# How to dynamically add dates to Ionic ion-datetime

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic7

I'm trying to create an Ionic calendar using ion-datetime. In it I want to mark several dates of the Month view. Those dates are retrieved through an API. The issue is here that the calendar is already drawn by the time I receive the dates from the API. If I add the dates programmatically, they are added as expected. I use the following code:

```
  async ngOnInit() {
    this.highlightedDates.push({ date: '2023-09-06', textColor: '#ffffff', backgroundColor: '#ff7f00' });
    this.token = await this.storage.get('token');
    this.getDates(JSON.stringify(this.token)).subscribe(data => {
    for (let i=0; i<data.dates.date.length; i++) {
      this.highlightedDates.push({ date: data.dates.date[i], textColor: '#ffffff', backgroundColor: '#ff7f00' });
    }
    console.log(this);
  }
```

In the console I can see several dates, however only the 6th of the month shows up on the calendar. Any idea on how to reflect all dates on the calendar? I use the most recent Ionic version (7.4.0).

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work. Together with the to-be highlighted days, I also added the boundary values to the API response. That doesn't work. So I now calculate the boundaries in the code itself, and pass only the dates in the API.
Also had to move the code from ngOnInit to ionViewDidEnter. The boundaries seem to work with ngOnInit and not ionViewDidEnter, and for the dates the other way around.